# Unable to publish localstream using owt-client-javascript on owt-server

Tags: javascript, webrtc, intel, openwebrtc

I have successfully installed intel **owt-server** on ubuntu 18.04 as described in https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-server.

Now I am using **owt-client-javascript** (https://github.com/open-webrtc-toolkit/owt-client-javascript) **conference sample** to initiate conference calls.

But the stream is not being published. it stuck's at the conference.publish() promise that has no response. browser only shows local-stream while remote-stream is undefined.

**Server Side logs**

```
3 rooms in this service.

sampleRoom Id: 60559c62eadc1f2b4ab9ba7c

GET / 304 10.831 ms - -

GET /scripts/index.js 304 2.627 ms - -

GET /scripts/rest-sample.js 304 2.136 ms - -

GET /scripts/owt.js 304 0.962 ms - -

POST /tokens/ 200 1642.836 ms - 256
```

**client-side logs are**

```
Streams in conference: 1

2 Participants in conference: 1

owt.js:9 2021-03-24T14:03:12.176Z Empty candidate.

owt.js:9 2021-03-24T14:03:13.144Z ICE connection state changed to checking

owt.js:9 2021-03-24T14:03:13.144Z Remote stream added.

owt.js:9 2021-03-24T14:03:13.145Z Remote stream added.

owt.js:9 2021-03-24T14:03:28.166Z ICE connection state changed to disconnected
```

**Below is the remoteStream Object**

```
addEventListener: ƒ (t,r)
clearEventListener: ƒ (t)
dispatchEvent: ƒ (t)
extraCapabilities: e {audio: e, video: e}
removeEventListener: ƒ (t,r)
settings: e
audio: Array(1)
0: e {codec: e, _trackId: undefined}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
video: Array(1)
0: e
bitrate: NaN
codec: e {name: "vp8", profile: undefined}
frameRate: 24
keyFrameInterval: 100
resolution: e {width: 640, height: 480}
rid: undefined
_trackId: undefined
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
attributes: undefined
id: "60559c62eadc1f2b4ab9ba7c-common"
origin: undefined
source: e
audio: "mixed"
data: undefined
video: "mixed"
__proto__: Object
stream: undefined
__proto__: r
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```